# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object not found inside r function

Tags: r, function

I would like to use function in R to automate a program.
This following function works and returns different result if I change time and status.

```
survplot <- function(time, status){
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~GRP, data)
}
print(survplot(data$TIME_OS, data$STATUS_OS))
```

Now, I want to do this :

```
survplot <- function(time, status){
  fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status)~GRP, data)
  surv_pvalue(fit=fit, data=data, method="survdiff")
  pvalue <- paste("Log-rank P-value:", format(pvalue$pval, digits=4))
}
print(survplot(data$TIME_OS, data$STATUS_OS))
```

But the following error occurs ...

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'status' not found
```

Basically, I am working with SAS and use the MACRO system :

```
%macro survplot(time=,status=)
proc lifetest data=data;
time time*status(0);
run;
%mend;
%survplot(time=TIME_OS,status=STATUS_OS);
```

I thought R functions could work the same way...

Comment: You dont have anything named `pvalue` saved in your function, so when you try for `pvalue$pval` there is nothing there. Did you mean to assign the line `surv_pvalue(fit=fit, data=data, method="survdiff")` as as object in the function named `pvalue`? Also, what would you like your function to return?  `fit`? `pvalue`?

Comment: I would like to add the ggsurvplot function which takes the pvalue with the pval option in order to draw my curves. So, in this function "survplot", I call ggsurvplot(data...., pval=pvalue) to output curves

Comment: Hi @guillaume, what you described in the comment above is markedly different than what your question is asking - which doesn't reference using `ggsurvplot` at all. Could you edit your question to describe *exactly* what you want to do and include data sufficient to recreate the issue? These edits may assist in getting better, faster help. Good luck!